# Will Windows 10 upgrade support Windows Movie Maker?

Tags: windows-movie-maker, windows-10

With every upgrade, Windows Movie Maker has gotten less useful for me, e.g., we can't burn DVD like we could Windows 7.  I wonder if Movie Maker is going to be available with the new upgrade?

Comment: We are not a forecasting oracle

Comment: @random - This actually has an answer that can be verified.

Comment: @random I don't think the OP is looking for an "oracle's forecast". More likely he's hoping for an authoritative answer. If an authoritative answer doesn't exist so be it, but let's give the SU community a chance to respond first.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to install [Windows Essentials 2012](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-essentials-2012-system-requirements) on the current released build of Windows 10.

I had no problem running the current version of Movie Maker on Windows 10.

It can be [downloaded on this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/download-windows-essentials#wetabs=we2012)

[image]